# Not registering when the trigger is pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, steamvr

i have some code, that when the trigger of the right hand controller is pressed, it shoots a gun, however it doesn't appear to be working, i've tried to add a debug into the actual TriggerPressed section, and that doesn't show up in the log when i click it in game either, im just not sure where this problem is orginating from, and im stumped as to why it isn't working. It also compiles, so any guidance is appreciated

Edit: Not sure of its importance but decided to add this anyway, im using oculus rift controller's

Here's the (edit: UPDATED) code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using EZEffects;

public class adamadam : MonoBehaviour
{

public SteamVR_TrackedController controllerRight;

private SteamVR_TrackedObject trackedObj;
private SteamVR_Controller.Device device;

private SteamVR_TrackedController controller;

public EffectTracer TracerEffect;
public Transform muzzleTransform;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

 //  controller = controllerRight.GetComponent<SteamVR_TrackedController>();
        controller.TriggerClicked += TriggerPressed;
      //  trackedObj = controllerRight.GetComponent<SteamVR_TrackedObject>();
}

private void TriggerPressed(object sender, ClickedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Log("Clicked");
    ShootWeapon();
}


public void ShootWeapon()
{
    RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
    Ray ray = new Ray(muzzleTransform.position, muzzleTransform.forward);

    device = SteamVR_Controller.Input((int)trackedObj.index);
    device.TriggerHapticPulse(750);
    TracerEffect.ShowTracerEffect(muzzleTransform.position, 
muzzleTransform.forward, 250f);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 5000f))
    {
        if (hit.collider.attachedRigidbody)
        {
            Debug.Log("Hit" + hit.collider.gameObject.name);
        }
    }

}



}
```

Comment: is `adamadam` active and enabled in your Scene right from the beginning?

Comment: it is, the script is attached to the gun object, which is attached to the right controller object, which is further attached to the camera rig.

Comment: But isn't the controller object disabled by default until the Steam Controller is tracked? Could you check that by adding `OnDisable(){ Debug.Log("Disabled " + name, this);`?

Comment: @derHugo sure, where would you like me to add it? Same place as the last debug log? Edit: Sorry i mean under TriggerPressed

Comment: to the script in general. It is a method

Comment: sorry, miss read it, this is what the log now returns https://gyazo.com/0aae455902d2022b6c8ae26cf5210668 EDIT: is it worth noting that, upon starting the unity project it defaults to oculus sdk and i have to use an sdk switcher to change it to steamvr, while the game is running?

Comment: wait you get an exception? Was this already there before? It seems that the `controller` is not found and therefore you get an exception in the line `controller.TriggerClicked += TriggerPressed;`, right? Or laready earlier if you didn't reference `controllerRight` in the inspector. -> So the event listener is never added since you have an exception before

Comment: yeah that only just appeared though, after adding the new method. How do i fix the finding the controller part? Because i thought i dont that correctly, im confused as this has only just showed

Comment: @derHugo, i decided to run it again ,removing the new method and its still there https://gyazo.com/6fbf5fbda22a1fde5ee4dc0e9e3d17e9 i have also referenced the controller in the inspector

Comment: Try to make `controllerRight` directly of type `SteamVR_TrackedController` instead of GameObject. than you can get rid of that `GetComponent` call and be sure the component is there

Comment: @derHugo okay i'll try to do that now, im a complete novice at this, and im not too sure on how to do that, but i'll give it a shot and let you know

Comment: @derHugo Just updated the code with that, i also still have the exception Edit: in the inspector, it now says none for the controller and  icant add anything to it either

Comment: you should be able to drag in the controller again. Check again if there is still a `SteamVR_TrackedController` component on the controller

Comment: @derHugo removing the script and re-adding it fixed that problem, i now dragged it in, the exception still persists though and is still not working